# Evernote webhook request form not working

Tags: webhooks, evernote

I'm trying to register an evernote webhook. But seems like the register form is not working.

Evernote webhook register form:
[image]

I filled the form, clicked "submit", but always got following error response:

```
{"error":"RecordInvalid","description":"Record validation errors","details":{"base":[{"description":"Question: cannot be blank","error":"BlankValue"}]}}
```

Does anyone encountered the same problem? Or know the solution for this problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Experienced this too. The form is broken.

Comment: Sure hope they fix this soon. I need to request a webhook in the very near future!

Comment: Is this still broken?

Comment: @akhaku Yes, it's still broken.

Comment: Hey @Caesar we are looking into the issue. It might take some time but I'll try to comment here when we have it resolved.

Comment: Hi @aug, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Caesar I believe this should be fixed now. Let us know if you have issues! And thanks for bringing it up :)

Comment: @aug Thank you very much for your help! I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 1):

The form is working, but it is missing the field to indicate any note filter you want on the webhook so you're not notified of every note created or updated by every user.

[EN's docs](https://dev.evernote.com/support/faq.php#activatehook) suggest the form should include this element, "To register a Webhook, complete a Developer Support request. Include the URL your Webhook will access and the Note filter that should be applied. Once we’ve received your request, your Webhook will be activated, typically within 1–2 business days. You’ll receive email confirmation when your Webhook has been activated."